# Overwriting events with Chrome extensions

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I am building a Chrome extension and I'm facing some troubles while trying to overwrite some JavaScript events on the page the extension is going to run on.

I've built a mockup page with HTML that looks like so:

```js
document.querySelector('#f').onclick = function() {
  document.body.innerHTML += 'you clicked';
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <button id='f'>click me</button>
</body>

</html>
```

The extension is supposed to change the onclick event. So here we have the content script:

```
document.querySelector('#f').onclick = function() {
  document.body.innerHTML += 'it is the extension';
}
```

But instead both of the functions are executed **independently** from each other - The `innerHTML` added when you click on the button is `you clickedit is the extension`. Why are both functions executed and how can i solve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Your script runs on a different context than the scripts that run in the page's context.

As stated [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Content_scripts#Content_script_environment):

> content scripts get a "clean" view of the DOM. This means:
>
> - Content scripts cannot see JavaScript variables defined by page scripts.
> - If a page script redefines a built-in DOM property, the content script sees the original version of the property, not the redefined version

So actually your code doesn't redefine the `onClick` property, rather it adds an event listener, so you need to make your script run as a "page script" by injecting it into a `<script>` element.

A possible solution [using a utility](https://github.com/arikw/extension-page-context) I've built for that purpose:

```js
await runInPageContext(() => {
  document.querySelector('#f').onclick = function() {
    document.body.innerHTML += 'it is the extension';
  }
});
```